# Calculating Standard Error Vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, standard-error

I'm trying to add a standard error function into excel using VBA, what I have so far is just a variation of a standard deviation function. I got the function online and changed it so in the last line it's divided by the square root of the total data points. This doesn't seem to work for me.

Edit: When I try to use the function on the Excel spreadsheet, it comes up as 0 regardless of what the data set is.

```
Function StdErr(numbers As Range) As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xbar As Double
    Dim x As Double
    xbar = WorksheetFunction.Average(numbers)
    For i = 1 To numbers.Count
        x = x + (numbers.Item(i).Value - xbar) ^ 2
    Next i
    SrdErr = (x / numbers.Count) / (Sqr(numbers.Count))
End Function
```

Comment: It doesn't work because? Do you get an error, or does it not produce the right value, what happens?

Comment: When I try to use the function on the Excel spreadsheet, it comes up as 0 regardless of what the data set is. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Is there any reason that you are not using the worksheet function for standard deviation?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate standard error, which can be done with existing worksheet functions, but can't be done in just one function.

Comment: But the numerator  *can* be so calculated. Also -- are you sure that you want to use the population size in your standard deviation calculation rather than the pop size - 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple problems with your code: (1) the last statement misspells the function name `SrdErr` instead of `StdErr`. This is why you get 0. (2) The function definition itself isn't correct, according to [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214076).

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Function StdErr(numbers As Range) As Double
    Dim StdDev As Double
    Dim Size As Integer

    StdDev = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(numbers)
    Size = WorksheetFunction.Count(numbers)

    StdErr = StdDev / Sqr(Size)
End Function
```

It's a good idea to include `Option Explicit` so you can avoid silly spelling mistakes like this.

Comment: Thanks! After I fixed the typo the calculation was off, but now it works!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get zero is because of a typo.

`SrdErr =` at the end should be `StdErr =`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it fairly directly:

```
Function StdErr(numbers As Range) As Double
    StdErr = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(numbers) / (Sqr(numbers.Count))
End Function
```

The formula you had seemed to have both an incorrect denominator and a missing square root in the over-all numerator, at least is you are trying to do [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error)